# flutter pubspec.yaml exit code 65

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

My Flutter pubspec.yaml does not get the packages. This error show:

```
Error on line 30, column 22 of pubspec.yaml: Invalid version constraint: Expected version number after "^" in "^^4.2.1", got "^4.2.1".

   ╷

30 │   animated_text_kit: ^^4.2.1

   │                      ^^^^^^^

   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65
```

This is my dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  audioplayers: ^0.16.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I checked indentation, versions and so on.

What should i do?

Comment: Can you add your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Check indentation (tabs vs spaces), other characters, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 65 on pubspec.yaml indicates that the file is not well-formatted. You need to check the file again where is the problem or share the full yaml file so that I can check. Or try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get` in the terminal if you are confident about the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code and then run flutter pub get refer documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.16.1
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
```